# Yii2 ORM smart get related model

Tags: php, orm, yii2

I have 3 Yii2 ActiveRecord models: `Emplpoyee`, `Department` and `Organization`.

`Employee` must have either one `Department` or one `Organization`, that is ensured by validation (fails if both `department_id` and `organization_id` are `null` or both are not `null`). `Department` must have one `Organization`, it's a standard yii2 ORM relation via `hasOne()`.

Gii created this code for employee/organization relation:

```
class Employee
{
    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(app\models\Organization::class, ['id' => 'organization_id']);
    }
}
```

So when I call `$employeeObject->organization`, I will get `null` if `organization_id` in SQL table is null.

I want to modify this standard getter function to return `$this->department->organization` in be able to get `$employee->organization` via magic getter like this: if an employee has department - organization gets from department, otherwise - via standard relation.

**Update:** if I write:

```
/**
 * @return ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOrganization()
{
    if (!is_null($this->organization_id)) {
        return $this->hasOne(app\models\Organization::class, ['id' => 'organization_id']);
    } elseif (!is_null($this->department)) {
        return $this->department->getOrganization();
    } else {
        // We should not be here, but what if we are?
    }
}
```

How do I handle a situation of broken relation to `Department` or both `organization_id` and `department_id` is `null`? Which `ActiveQuery` do I return?

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried writing your own getter? Show us some code.

Comment: Added empirical code. I don't get how to handle a broken relation? Throw Exception?

Comment: Just return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations definitions are used to build SQL query for related models. In some cases (eager loading, joins) query needs to be created before you get actual object, so you cannot use `if ($this->organization_id)` because `$this` is not actual model and `$this->organization_id` will alway be `null`. The only thing that you can get is to define regular relations without any conditions and getter method (`getOrganizationModel()`), which will return correct organization from relations:

```
class Employee extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getDepartment() {
        return $this->hasOne(Department::class, ['id' => 'department_id']);
    }

    public function getOrganization() {
        return $this->hasOne(Organization::class, ['id' => 'organization_id']);
    }

    public function getOrganizationModel() {
        if ($this->organization_id !== null) {
            return $this->organization;
        }

        return $this->department->organization;
    }
}

class Department extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getOrganization() {
        return $this->hasOne(Organization::class, ['id' => 'organization_id']);
    }
}
```

Then you can query records with both relations and use getter to get organization:

```
$employees = Employe::find()->with(['department.organization', 'organization'])->all();
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    echo $employee->getOrganizationModel()->name;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is definitely a better way to handle it. I've removed my answer involving `via()` in favor of this as this handles better joins & eager loading.

Comment: This is correct, though completely non-elegant, alas. I wonder if there is a way to workaround an eager loading problem with @SalemOuerdani answer. Like checking if we are in eager loading mode and lazy-load outstanding model instead.

Comment: @SergeAx If you don't care about eager loading and joins, you can use regular getter with `Organization::findOne($this->organization_id)` and some internal caching. The whole point of relations is to support eager loading and joins - you don't need to fight with relations if you don't need these features.